# How to standardize the encoded dates in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

My instructor provided me with hundreds of dates that I'm going to use for aging an accounts receivables. My problem is that, some of the dates are in mm/dd/yyyy and some are in dd/mm/yyyy. How do I standardize these dates so that I could use it for computation. I tried the format cells>date>mm/dd/yyy but when I use it for EDATE, some appears to be #VALUE.. What should I do..??

Comment: Do you know which entries are in which format? If so you can add a flag to the data and convert to YYYY-MM-DD.

Answer (score 1):

There are only two possible cases for an individual cell:

1. the cell has a true date *(a number formatted as a date)*
2. the cell has text that **looks** like a date *(an imposter)*

True dates will respond to changing the format, imposters will not respond.  You may have a combination of these two types of cells.
To see what you have, just use tilda, that is toggle <kbd>Cntrl</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd>.  True dates will display their underlying numeric value, text cells will be unchanged.

Once you have identified any text cells you can fix them either manually or via a macro, or via a formula.

Comment: "some of the dates are in mm/dd/yyyy and some are in dd/mm/yyyy." - Your answer doesn't address dates that are real dates but ambiguous. For example `01/02/2016`. Is this `dd/mm/yyyy` or `mm/dd/yyyy`?

Comment: @DavidPostill  My point is that **it does not matter!!**  As long as they are "true dates", we can force a common format by formatting the cells in one fell swoop

Comment: <shrug> Swapping mm and dd can make a big difference for some applications ...